# How to implement code in two different UIAlertActions from a single UIAlertController?

Tags: swift, xcode, qr-code, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am new in Swift and Xcode world. In my app, user has to choose if he/she wants to scan QRCode to get data from it, or if he/she wants to enter data(type String) and generate QRCode via that String. I am trying to implement QRScanner and QRGenerator but I am stuck.

I am using UIAlertController which has two UIAlertActions for now.
After I get my data using QRScanner/QRGenerator, I have to store it in my custom UITableViewCell. Should I be using UIAlertController or something else? Any tips and tricks how should I do this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNFDJ.jpg
This is what I have for now.

```swift
@IBAction func cameraButtonClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


            var textField = UITextField()

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "What do you want to do?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let scanAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SCAN QR", style: .default) { (action) in



            }
        let manualAction = UIAlertAction(title: "MANUAL", style: .default) { (action) in



        }

        alert.addAction(scanAction)
        alert.addAction(manualAction)


        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

I tried several different ways to make this work, but my app is constantly crashing. As I said, I am new in this world, so any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: So your question is this: how to create a qr code reader and generator in Swift. (It doesn't matter whether you use an alert or not.) I suggest you study up on this topic a bit. There are plenty of resources online. Here are a few:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-create-a-qr-code 

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code 

https://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/

Comment: If you want help with a crash, it's a good idea to supply the message that comes with the crash and a stack trace.  (There are lots of answers on here about how to obtain those if you're new to that concept.)